# Data Partition in Supervised Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, supervised-learning

I have tried to train one Hidden Markov Model(HMM) tagger to extract some user defined
entities. I am trying to run one classifier to extract various relationships and resolving
ambiguity of the extracted entities. 
In both these supervised algorithms I have kept 80% of the data for training, and 20% for testing.
I am not comparing any model performance so not keeping any data for validation or cross
validation. Am I fine? 
I tried to read some materials like,
[Stackexchange Post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set), [Previous post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976452/whats-is-the-difference-between-train-validation-and-test-set-in-neural-networ),[Previous Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803228/purpose-of-test-data-in-supervised-learning) and a [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_set)

Comment: fine with what? And if you are not comparing anything then why you have test set at all?

Comment: I meant to say is my approach fine? In test data I am comparing performance of chosen model with training data. By comparison I tried to mean performance comparison among various models.

Comment: in order to answer if the setting is ok we will need exact description of what you do and what you are **trying to achieve**

Comment: I have user defined labels. I am trying to train one HMM tagger on it as if to extract NERs. Suppose the tagged data is tagged with PERS and LOC in one document, I am trying to train one simple multiclass classifier say NB, with these tagged entity base strings labeled with relation like PERS-LOC, I am now training the NB on this new data to extract relations.