# Textblob sentiment algorithm

Tags: sentiment-analysis, textblob

Does anyone know how textblob sentiment is working? I know it is working based on Pattern but I could not find any article or document explain how pattern assigns polarity value to a sentence.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34519114/5575289 
I think this link explains what you need.

Comment: The answer by gench should be indicated as the right answer while the one by DhruvPathak is partial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the code of textblog sentiment module:
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/90cc87ab0f9e25f37379079840ec43aba59af440/textblob/en/sentiments.py

As you can see, it has a training set with preclassified movie reviews, when you give a new text for analysis, it uses NaiveBayes classifier to classify the new text's polarity in `pos` and `neg` probabilities.

Answer (score 7):

By default, it calculates average **polarity** and **subjectivity** over each word in a given text using a dictionary of adjectives and their hand-tagged scores. It actually uses [pattern](https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/d25511f9ca7ed9356b801d8663b8b5168464e68f/pattern/text/en/wordnet/__init__.py#L490) library for that, which takes the individual word scores from [sentiwordnet](https://github.com/aesuli/sentiwordnet).

If you call sentiment scores by specifying NaiveBayesAnalyzer such as

> TextBlob("The movie was excellent!", analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())

then it will calculate the sentiment score by NaiveBayesAnalyzer trained on a dataset of movie reviews.

Comment: This should be indicated as the right answer while the one by DhruvPathak is partial. Here is a link to several issues addressing this point on the Github of the library: github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/344#issuecomment-732193942

Comment: I second @ArnoldVialfont on this. gench's answer seems to be the complete and correct one.