# Calculate Conditional Probability Python

Tags: python, probability

I am trying to calculate the probability of an outcome with a hierarchical tree structure                                  [image]

> The top is computer Computer A, the next 2 are Computer B & C, and the
>   last 4 are Computer BD, BE, and CD, CE. I am trying to find the
>   probability that if computer A gets infected with a virus what is the
>   probability that B or C gets infected with a virus. And if B or C gets
>   infected what is the probability that BD, BE, CD, CE gets infected
>   with a virus

I want to run 100 trials to find the answer. I am new to doing probability on python. However here is the code I have so far:

```
import random, time

#prob that computers will get virus
CompA = 0.50
CompB = .25 
CompC = .25
CompBD = .125
CompBE= .125
CompCD= .125
CompCE= .125



def generate():
    x = random.random()
    if x =< CompA: #Computer A has virus
       prob_compa= sum(generate() for i in range(100)) #prob that Comp A has virus  in a 100 rounds
       print (prob_compa/100 + 'percent chance of getting virus')

        try:
            if CompB<.125:
                 prob_compa sum(generate() for i in range(100)) #prob that Comp B has virus  in a 100 rounds
                print (prob_compa/100 + 'percent chance of getting virus')
                 elif CompB<.125:
                 prob_compa= sum(generate() for i in range(100)) #prob that Comp C is sick  in a 100 rounds
       print (prob_compa/100 + 'percent chance of getting virus')

      #I continue this method for the rest of the tree
```

Is there a better way and simpler way for me to get the results?
**random.uniform**???

Comment: I think you do not have to perform a simulation. Can't you derive this using the *Markov blanket*? This is after all a nice *probability graph*.

Comment: hmm never heard of it.. will this feature present an easier way to calculate my desired outcome?

Comment: "If A gets infected, what's the probability that B gets infected" -- this is actually plain simple [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), no need for more advanced tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
#python_test2.py
import random, time

virus_probabilities= { "CompA" : 0.50, "CompB" : .25, "CompC" : .25, "CompBD" : .125,
                   "CompBE" : .125, "CompCD" : .125, "CompCE" : .125}

def check_probability(computer_name, n_repetitions = 100):
    prob_comp, repetitions = 0, 0
    p_computer = virus_probabilities[computer_name]
    while repetitions < n_repetitions:
     x = random.random()
     if x <= p_computer:
          prob_comp += 1
     repetitions += 1
    print ("{0} % chance of getting virus on {1}".format(round(prob_comp/100.0, 2), computer_name))

for key in virus_probabilities:
     check_probability(key, 1000)
```

When I run the file from the console, I get:

```
mabe@ubuntu:~/Desktop $ python test_2.py
2.49 % chance of getting virus on CompB
2.6 % chance of getting virus on CompC
5.07 % chance of getting virus on CompA
1.38 % chance of getting virus on CompBE
1.16 % chance of getting virus on CompBD
1.18 % chance of getting virus on CompCD
1.36 % chance of getting virus on CompCE
```

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant code from mabe02, perhaps worth adding a very minor improvement to the core function avoid confusion/future bugs:

```
def check_probability(computer_name, n_repetitions):
    prob_comp, repetitions = 0, 0
    p_computer = virus_probabilities[computer_name]
    while repetitions < n_repetitions:
     x = random.random()
     if x <= p_computer:
          prob_comp += 1
     repetitions += 1
    print ("{0} % changes of getting virus on {1}".format(round(prob_comp/n_repetitions, 2), computer_name))
```

Doing so would actually bring probabilities closer to the starting one which is expected as n_repetitions gets bigger.

Although for more specifics on conditional probability you should definitely have a look at this post: [A simple explanation of Naive Bayes Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059594/a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification/20556654#20556654)